# VBA code throwing a run time error but still works

Tags: vba, excel

I have written a very simple VBA code to that if column 2 is populated and column 1 and 4 are empty then to populate column 1 with the current date and column 4 with the current time.

Here is the code that I have:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
  If (Target.Column = 2) And Target.Offset(0, -1).Value = "" Then
    Target.Offset(0, 2) = Format(Now(), "HH:MM:SS")
    Target.Offset(0, -1) = Date
    End If
  End Sub
```

and it works but I get a Run-Time error when I fill in column 2, thoughts?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3):

That is because the event is firing again when the data is filled in the first column.  This causes an error because from the first column there is no column at `.Offset(0,-1)`

To stop this split your If to a nested if:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If (Target.Column = 2) Then
        If Target.Offset(0, -1).Value = "" Then
            Target.Offset(0, 2) = Format(Now(), "HH:MM:SS")
            Target.Offset(0, -1) = Date
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Now if it is any other column then the inner if will not fire.

---

Another recommendation is to use `Application.EnableEvents` to stop the events temporarily so we do not fire recursively:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If (Target.Column = 2) Then
        If Target.Offset(0, -1).Value = "" Then
            Application.EnableEvents = False
                Target.Offset(0, 2) = Format(Now(), "HH:MM:SS")
                Target.Offset(0, -1) = Date
            Application.EnableEvents = True
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Could you alternatively `EnableEvents = False`? Or would you still get the error?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, that makes sense!

Comment: You can and it would solve it, but as it is only calling the sub two more times  I figured no big deal. @BruceWayne

Comment: @BruceWayne no the error will still happen if column 1 is changed manually.

Comment: @ScottCraner - Ah yes, duh. I see that now.

Answer (score 2):

...and throwing in my 2c

`Target` can be >1 cell and potentially span multiple columns, so you need to account for that.  Also plan never to leave event handling disabled in the case of a run-time error (even though in this case strictly speaking you don't need to turn handling off).

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim rng, c
    'only handle if change is in col2
    Set rng = Application.Intersect(Target, Me.Columns(2))

    If Not rng Is Nothing Then
        On Error GoTo haveError '<< ensure events are not left turned off
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        For Each c In rng.Cells
            If c.Offset(0, -1).Value = "" Then
                c.Offset(0, 2) = Format(Now(), "HH:MM:SS")
                c.Offset(0, -1) = Date
            End If
        Next c
    End If

haveError:
    Application.EnableEvents = True '<< switch event handling back on
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
  If (Target.Column = 2) And Target.Offset(0, 2).Value = "" Then
    Target.Offset(0, 2) = Format(Now(), "HH:MM:SS")
    Target.Offset(0, -1) = Date
    End If
  End Sub
```

This will work and won't throw the de-bugger.

Comment: Well yes, because you're testing something totally different than the original issue.

Comment: Your code will execute the main set of commands if column D is blank, even if column A is **not** blank.  The OP's code will only execute the commands if column A is blank.